# The number of all possible positive integral values of $\alpha$ for which the roots of the quadratic $6x^2 -11x +\alpha$ are rational numbers are?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

the number of all possible positive integral values of $\alpha$ for which the roots of the quadratic $6x^2 -11x +\alpha$ are rational numbers are?

My attempt:-

The roots are given by $\frac{-11 \pm \sqrt{121-24\alpha}}{12}$,

Beyond this I'm not sure what to do, any suggestions?

Comment: $121 - 24\alpha$ have to be square

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the term "integral value". What do you mean?

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt Integers.

Comment: @TonyPizza, so I just have to equate this to as many possible squares as I can to find the number of possible values, or is there a more elegant method?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig is this a synonym for integers or an an imprecise term? Honestly is the first time seeing this term for me

Comment: Since $6 \times 24 >121$ you only need to check $0,1,2,3,4,5$

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt  Integral values is a synonym for the integers.  When used in this way, integral is an adjective referring to the integers.

Comment: @mathandphysicsforever I don't know if that's the only method. I only commented based on the formula you worte. I will tell you if I can think of something.

Comment: @Henry I thought same at first but later I realised it can be minus for example with -2 you get 169

Comment: @Henry Note that $\alpha$ can be negative.  For instance, $6x^2 - 11x - 2 = 6x^2 - 12x + x - 2 = 6x(x - 2) + 1(x - 2) = (6x + 1)(x - 2)$ has rational roots.

Comment: *Hint*: Alternatively, the only possible factorisation of $6x^2-11x+\alpha$ are $(6x+?)(x+?)$ or $(2x+?)(3x+?)$ and look at the coefficient of $x$.

Comment: @user10354138, ah tysm!

Comment: @N.F.Taussig We know $\alpha>0$ from the question.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig If you allow negative $\alpha$, the number of such $\alpha$ is infinite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the solutions of $6x^2 - 11x + a = 0$ are solutions of $(6x)^2 -11(6x) + 6a = 0$ and replacing $6x$ by $y$ these roots are rational if and only if roots to $y^2 -11y + 6a$ are rational. But this is monic integral polynomial hence rational roots must be integers. Now let's say $m, n$ are the roots then $m + n = 11$ and $mn = 6a$ so all possible values of $a$ can be given as $mn/6$ when $m + n = 11$ and $6$ divides $mn$.

Now assume $6$ divides $mn$ and by symmetry let's assume $3\vert m$ or in other words $m = 3k$ for some integer $k$. Thus $n = (11 - 3k)$ and $mn = 3k(11-3k)$. This would be divisible by $6$ if and only if $k(11-3k)$ is divisible by $2$ which is true for any value of $k$ so all possible values of $a$ are $\dfrac{3k(11-3k)}{6} = \dfrac{k(11-3k)}{2}$ for any integer $k$.